# Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a field. Prove that $\mathbb{Q}\subset K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I don't have any ideas for this one. The hint the book gives is to prove that $\mathbb{Z}\subset K$ but I don't see how that helps.

Comment: Have you managed to show that $\mathbb Z\subset K$?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you know that $\mathbb{Z} \subset K$ you get that $n^{-1} \in K$ for each non-zero integer, as being a field it must contain the multiplicative inverses. From there $m(n^{-1})$ for each integer $m$ and you are done.

To show that  $\mathbb{Z} \subset K$ use that $1 \in K$ and $1+ 1 + \dots + 1$ will never be $0$, and that you also have $-1 \in K$.

Comment: Why is it important to show that 1+1+1+...+1 will never be 0?

Comment: When you consider the additive subgroup generated by $1$ you need to make sure that it is infinite (cyclic), and thus $\mathbb{Z}$. Consider the case $K=\mathbb{Z}/7 \mathbb{Z} $ for example to see why this is important  (of course that one is not contained in the reals.)

Answer (score 0):

The hint in the book is to show that $\mathbb Z\in K$.  Here are some further hints.

**Hint:** Show that $\frac12\in K$.  Show that $\frac13\in K$.  Show that $\frac23\in K$.

Once you've shown those, you should be well on your way to showing that $\frac{a}{b}\in K$ for all $\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

K is a field. So $1 \in K$ therefore: $\mathbb{Z} \subset K$. Because $1+1+1+...+1 \in K$ 
Now $\mathbb{Q}$ is the smallest field wich contains $\mathbb{Z}$. Because $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}$